# Mutli instance in deep link android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have Issued with the deep link. when I want to open Activity, I got 2 instances of my app. the first one works but the other one won't. as I search for a solution, found some way to solve this issue. like add :

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

but either after add, this line to manifest inside the related activity section still has 2 instances in the deep link.

for example with tools: replace handle priority and set it for a new instance and just show one instance? (I think one of the instances is a new app and the other one is an old app.)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `singleInstance` as it will have singleInstance in your app.

Comment: The activity you want to redirect is the launcher activity ?